# EmberJS nesting on index page not working?

Tags: ember.js

I've got a very simple EmberJS app running with the following Route:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('index', {path: '/'}, function(){
        this.resource('photos');
    });
    this.resource('about');
});
```

When I visit the index page at http://my.localhost/myember/ I'm expecting to see the output **h1** from the root/index page, followed by the content of the photos resource, at the end of my template where I placed the {outlet} tag:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
    <p>My Index Page</p>
    {{outlet}}
</script>
```

However, all I'm seeing is the My Index Page heading and no photos, I only see the expected output when I visit /#/photos

Why is this, I want this behaviour on the index page rather than /#/photos

Comment: I think I got the cat by the tail, I think I need to use the render helper instead...

Comment: The render helper does not sound like the right solution. It rather sounds like you should redirect your user from the index route to the photos route. It's the right behaviour of Ember to show you just the contents of the index page. Ember does not automatically transition to your photos route just because it is nested inside it.

Comment: I don't want to redirect, I want to embed a filmstrip which is supposed to be in a separate view, and has it's own model.

Comment: I'm able to render/embed another view, but not too sure how to get it to load data via it's controller method. Typically this gets done by the model member function in a route.

Comment: It looks like nesting can work, I just need to fix the URL. Getting the expected results on /#/photos instead of /#/

Answer (score 0):

In your case photos is a nested round under index, so it is natural to access it via index#/photos URL. The photos route content will be rendered in the outlet of the index template (as expected). So if you want to show your content from photos, right after the app navigates to index you can either make a redirect to photos (as already suggested) or you can just show your filmstrip as part of index - if you always show your contents, why you need nesting?

I am still learning, so accept my apologizes if my answer is not satisfactory enough.

Cheers!